# String and Garbage Collection

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I have a method in engine i'm using (andengine) :

```
public final void setText(String pString){...}
```

my app is updating score every 1s from static int

```
mScoreText.setText(""+PlayerSystem.mScore);
```

The problem is that this way every second a new String object is created , and after 1 minute i have 59 String objects to collect by GC and additional AbstractStringBuilders and init 's...

I've found a partial solution on andengine forums like this :

```
private static StringBuilder mScoreValue = new StringBuilder("000000");

private static final char[] DIGITS = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

mScoreValue.setCharAt(0, DIGITS[(PlayerSystem.mScore% 1000000) / 100000]);
mScoreValue.setCharAt(1, DIGITS[(PlayerSystem.mScore% 100000) / 10000]);
mScoreValue.setCharAt(2, DIGITS[(PlayerSystem.mScore% 10000) / 1000]);
mScoreValue.setCharAt(3, DIGITS[(PlayerSystem.mScore% 1000) / 100]);
mScoreValue.setCharAt(4, DIGITS[(PlayerSystem.mScore% 100) / 10]);
mScoreValue.setCharAt(5, DIGITS[(PlayerSystem.mScore% 10)]);
mScoreText.setText(mScoreValue.toString());
```

but the main problem remains, .toString() is returning new object every call

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Are you really concerned about one String per *second*? That seems not much to me, especially since I expect that every click or other event creates a new (event) object as well.

Comment: Yes. Stop caring. Garbage collectors are fast enough that worrying about one allocation per second is completely, phenomenally, out of proportion. Mindless fiddlework like that is what computers are best at -- let them do it and use your brainpower on something more rewarding.

Comment: Using that code would be a case of severe premature optimization. I reckon that in the end all the modulo operations, divisions, fetches from the array and setting characters in the StringBuilder would amount to a ton more processing than one String creation and the associated garbage collections. And like others pointed out, in the end you do create a String with toString(). If you're working with such limitations that allocating 60 small objects per minute is too much, Java isn't the language you'd want to use anyway. C or assembly would be closer to the mark there.

Comment: Wouldn't String.valueOf(PlayerSystem.mScore) be better as it skips the allocations of the StringBuilders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get around the fact that `Strings` are immutable and if your method takes a String, a new one will have to be created every time.

Comment: Well one could play with reflection and get a MUCH higher performance hit, but yep that's basically it. And 1 small object every second? Laughably uninteresting.

Comment: I agree that it's not really a big problem, but I believe conscientious programmer should be aware of these issues instead of just saying 'no worries, the compiler takes care of it'. It shows an interest in ability and a love for your craft.

Comment: @Russ C I don't agree. The most important thing for any optimization is to know how much you can win at best. <insert knuth quote here>. I would take every bet that if he was to profile the code he wouldn't even notice it. No chance in hell that this would make any difference when timing. (and believe me at least for javac I know exactly what code it'll generate for string concatenations - if there's no loop or function call involved forget it is a good rule there )

Comment: Let's agree to disagree; but I can't honestly accept that you think being aware of the impact of your code is not important. We should probably take this debate to programmers.stackexchange however.

Comment: I'm not active there, but sure interesting topic after all (will keep an eye out for a thread ;) ).

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a good candidate to use StringBuilder:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Or StringBuffer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Reasoning is:

StringBuffer is used to store character strings that will be changed (String objects cannot be changed). It automatically expands as needed. Related classes: String, CharSequence.

StringBuilder was added in Java 5. It is identical in all respects to StringBuffer except that it is not synchronized, which means that if multiple threads are accessing it at the same time, there could be trouble. For single-threaded programs, the most common case, avoiding the overhead of synchronization makes the StringBuilder very slightly faster.

Edit:
One thing you have to be careful of is how you use which ever SB class you pick.
The reason is (same in .Net too) if you have a usage like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(score.ToString() + "hello, world!");
```

You've still got 2 string concat operations, you're possibly actually making 3 strings there, one for `score.ToString()`, one to turn the literal `"hello, world!"` into a string, and one that contains the two concatenated together.
To get the best results, you need to use the SB's Append/insert/replace methods.

Comment: They are faster than ""+int but you end with the same number of objects

Comment: He will still have to call the `toString` method which will still create a new string object, so the problem is still there.

Comment: @SJuan76 `StringBuilder` wouldn't even be faster than the ""+int because of the overhead of creating a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` class. They are really only good for modifying a string some undetermined number of times in a loop.

Comment: Ultimately yes, you do have to create a string object, but what the Builder gives you is the ability to provide your concatenation without having to create multiple string objects. If you use it properly, you will generate less instances; See my edit for details.

Comment: Actually for `"" + someString` at least javac already creates a stringbuffer for that code (not sure about android, but I think it more than likely) so that's **EXACTLY** the same code - just less readable

Comment: This question is about Android development though.

Comment: @Russ C Sure and that's why I explicitly mention javac, because I haven't disassembled the source for android to be sure. But then the Android compiler usually optimizes more than javac for obvious reasons (having no JIT for a long time) and you HAVE to implement `string + string` with some function call anyhow so using a stringbuilder isn't an additional ste - so it's quite certain that it'll be the same.

Answer (score 3):

First, 120 objects in two minutes is nothing you should worry about, unless they are very large.

Second, String class holds a pool of all the Strings created. So, if you do

```
 String a = new String("Nabucodonosor King of Babilonia");
 String b = new String("Nabucodonosor King of Babilonia");
```

then `Nabucodonosor King of Babilonia` is stored only once in memory (but there are two String objects pointing at it). Check String#intern() for details.

And last, as Daniel points, as Strings are immutable there is no workaround using Strings. You could do some tricks (checking new value with old value, and creating the String only if they are different) but I doubt they compensate for the added complexity.